# Magento Extension Submission In Magento Connect

Tags: magento

I have developed simple magento extension by myself.

I am new two magento Extension development.

I have some queries before the extension submission in magento connect.

I have two products like `Product-A` and `Product-B`.

```
1)  Product-A => Basic feature -> Free
2)  Product-B => Basic feature of Product-A + Additional features -> Premium (paid)
```

Will Magento connect allow this as  two products or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Magento connect will approve and support the all kind of third party extensions.

No matter how the extensions will work and what are the functionality included with the extensions

Magento connect is a market place to promote the third party magento extensions.